# Matlab - ode45 - Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (1.136868e-13) at time t.

Tags: matlab, integral, ode45

I am programing a mathematical model from an article about angiogensis but when I try to plot the functions with the given parameteres and initial values, the program doesn't run for the entirety of the timespan I defined, showing a part of the graph but ending abrupty and showing the message:

```
Warning: Failure at t=5.404287e+01.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed
(1.136868e-13) at time t. 
> In ode45 (line 360)
```

The link for the full article with all the functions and the graphics I am trying to copy is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519316001429

I have tried other ode beside ode45, but this one was the only one that showed some promise...

The code I have currently is this:

Function for the first imagine of Fig. 3

```
function dy = derivatives1(t,i)

%% Default parameter set (Table C1)

V0 = 8E-3; % V0 = Reference VEGF concentration (uM)
A0 = 8E-3; % A0 = Reference Ang1/2 concentration (uM)
p0 = 8E-3; % p0 = Reference PDGF concentration (uM)
E0 = 8E-8; % E0 = Reference EC density (uM)
P0 = 4E-8; % P0 = Reference PC density (uM)
phi = 10^5; % phi = Average receptors per cell
v_kon = 1.88E4; % v_kon = VEGF/VEDGFR2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
v_koff = 0.99; % v_koff = VEGF/VEDGFR2 dissociation (h^-1)
v_kint = 0.86; % v_kint = VEGF internalisation (h^-1)
alphav = 3E-3; % alphav = VEGF delivery (uM^-1 h^-1)
deltav = 1; % deltav = VEGF decay (h^-1)
a1_kon = 417; % a1_kon = Ang1/Tie2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
a1_koff = 1.25; % a1_koff = Ang1/Tie2 dissociation (h^-1)
a1_kint = 1; % a1_kint = Ang1 internalisation (h^-1)
a2_kon = 417; % a2_kon = Ang2/Tie2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
a2_koff = 1.25; % a2_koff = Ang2/Tie2 dissociation (h^-1)
deltaa1 = 4.69; % deltaa1 = Ang1 decay (h^-1)
deltaa2 = 0.0625; % deltaa2 = Ang2 decay (h^-1)
deltaaw = 0.031; % deltaaw = Intracellular Ang2 decay (h^-1)
alphaa1 = 1E6; % alphaa1 = Ang1 production (h^-1)
alphaaw = 0.8; % alphaaw = Ang2 production (h^-1)
alphaa2 = 3; % alphaa2 = Ang2 release (h^-1)
alphap = 6.7E3; % alphap = PDGF production (h^-1)
p_kon = 1.88E4; % p_kon = PDGF/PDGFR-Beta association (uM^-1 h^-1)
p_koff = 0.86; % p_koff = PDGF/PDGFR-Beta dissociation (h^-1)
deltap = 1.2; % deltap = PDGF decay (h^-1)
theta = 0.0417; % theta = EC proliferation (h^-1)
rho = 0.02; % rho = EC death (h^-1)
kappa = 0.08; % kappa = PC proliferation (h^-1)
epsilon = 0.04; % epsilon = PC death (h^-1)
zeta = 5E5; % zeta = PC attachment (uM^-1 h^-1)
nu = 5E-3; % nu = PC detachment (h^-1)
eta = 0.01; % eta = Maturity increase (h^-1)
mu = 0.01; % mu = Maturity decrease (h^-1)
cep = 0.3; % cep = Threshold bound VEGF for EC proliferation
cd = 0.1; % cd = Threshold bound VEGF for EC death
ca = 0.3; % ca = Threshold bound Ang2 for EC proliferation
cpp = 0.02; % cpp = Threshold bound PDGF for PC proliferation
lambda = 8; % lambda = Ang2/Ang1 ratio for maturity decrease

%% Variable groupings

% Et = Total endothelial cells (uM)
Et = i(13) + i(14) + i(16);
% Pt = Total pericyte cells (uM)
Pt = i(15) + i(16);
% vb = Bound fraction of PDGFR-Beta receptors (None)
vb = i(3)/(i(2)+i(3));
% ab = Fraction of Tie2 receptors bound by Ang2 (None)
ab = i(9)/(i(7)+i(8)+i(9));
% pb = Bound fraction of PDGFR-Beta receptors (None)
pb = i(12)/(i(11)+i(12));

%% Model

dy = zeros(16,1);

% Biochemical Sub-Model

% Free VEGF
dy(1) = alphav/(((i(14)+i(16))/E0)+1) - v_kon*i(1)*i(2) + v_koff*i(3) - deltav*i(1);
% VEGFR2
dy(2) = - v_koff*i(1)*i(2) + (v_koff+v_kint)*i(3) + phi*theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/(ab^2+ca^2)))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(2);
% VEGF/VEGFR2
dy(3) = v_kon*i(1)*i(2) - (v_koff+v_kint)*i(3) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(3);
% Free Ang1
dy(4) = alphaa1*Pt - a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) + a1_koff*i(8) - deltaa1*i(4);
% Intracellular Ang2
dy(5) = alphaaw*(1+vb)*((A0/E0)*i(13)-i(5)) - deltaaw*i(5) - alphaa2*i(5)*((i(5))^2/((i(5))^2+((i(13)*A0)/(2*E0))^2)) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(5);
% Free Ang2
dy(6) = alphaa2*i(5)*((i(5))^2/((i(5))^2+((i(13)*A0)/(E0*2))^2)) - a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) + a2_koff*i(9) - deltaa2*i(6);
% Tie2
dy(7) = - a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) + (a1_koff+a1_kint)*i(8) - a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) + a2_koff*i(9) + phi*theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/(ab^2+ca^2)))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(7);
% Ang1/Tie2
dy(8) = a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) - (a1_koff+a1_kint)*i(8) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(8);
% Ang2/Tie2
dy(9) = a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) - a2_koff*i(9) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(9);
% Free PDGF
dy(10) = alphap*i(13) - p_kon*i(10)*i(11) + p_koff*i(12) - deltap*i(10);
% PDGFR-Beta
dy(11) = - p_kon*i(10)*i(11) + p_koff*i(12) + phi*kappa*(pb^2/(pb^2+cpp^2))*(1-(Pt/P0))*i(15) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2))*i(11));
% PDGF/PDGFR-Beta
dy(12) = p_kon*i(10)*i(11) - p_koff*i(12) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(12);

% Cell Dynamics Sub-model

% Immature ECs
dy(13) = theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/ab^2+ca^2))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/cd^2+vb^2)*i(13) - zeta*i(15)*i(13) + nu*i(16) + epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(16) - eta*(lambda^2/(lambda^2+(i(9)/i(8))^2))*i(13) + mu*((i(9)/i(8))^2/((i(9)/i(8))^2+lambda^2))*i(14);
% Mature ECs
dy(14) = - zeta*i(15)*i(14) + eta*(lambda^2/(lambda^2+(i(9)/i(8))^2))*i(13) + mu*((i(9)/i(8))^2/((i(9)/i(8))^2+lambda^2))*i(14);
% Free Pericytes
dy(15) = kappa*(pb^2/(pb^2+cpp^2))*(1-(Pt/P0))*i(15) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(15) - zeta*i(15)*(i(13)+i(14)) + nu*i(16);
% EC/PC Complex
dy(16) = zeta*i(15)*(i(13)+i(14)) - nu*i(16) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(15);

end
```

Function for the second imagine of Fig. 3

```
function dy = derivatives2(t,i)

%% Default parameter set (Table C1)

V0 = 8E-3; % V0 = Reference VEGF concentration (uM)
A0 = 8E-3; % A0 = Reference Ang1/2 concentration (uM)
p0 = 8E-3; % p0 = Reference PDGF concentration (uM)
E0 = 8E-8; % V0 = Reference EC density (uM)
P0 = 4E-8; % P0 = Reference PC density (uM)
phi = 10^5; % phi = Average receptors per cell
v_kon = 1.88E4; % v_kon = VEGF/VEDGFR2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
v_koff = 0.99; % v_koff = VEGF/VEDGFR2 dissociation (h^-1)
v_kint = 0.86; % v_kint = VEGF internalisation (h^-1)
alphav = 3E-3; % alphav = VEGF delivery (uM^-1 h^-1)
deltav = 1; % deltav = VEGF decay (h^-1)
a1_kon = 417; % a1_kon = Ang1/Tie2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
a1_koff = 1.25; % a1_koff = Ang1/Tie2 dissociation (h^-1)
a1_kint = 1; % a1_kint = Ang1 internalisation (h^-1)
a2_kon = 417; % a2_kon = Ang2/Tie2 association (uM^-1 h^-1)
a2_koff = 1.25; % a2_koff = Ang2/Tie2 dissociation (h^-1)
deltaa1 = 4.69; % deltaa1 = Ang1 decay (h^-1)
deltaa2 = 0.0625; % deltaa2 = Ang2 decay (h^-1)
deltaaw = 0.031; % deltaaw = Intracellular Ang2 decay (h^-1)
alphaa1 = 1E6; % alphaa1 = Ang1 production (h^-1)
alphaaw = 0.8; % alphaaw = Ang2 production (h^-1)
alphaa2 = 3; % alphaa2 = Ang2 release (h^-1)
alphap = 6.7E3; % alphap = PDGF production (h^-1)
p_kon = 1.88E4; % p_kon = PDGF/PDGFR-Beta association (uM^-1 h^-1)
p_koff = 0.86; % p_koff = PDGF/PDGFR-Beta dissociation (h^-1)
deltap = 1.2; % deltap = PDGF decay (h^-1)
theta = 0.0417; % theta = EC proliferation (h^-1)
rho = 0.02; % rho = EC death (h^-1)
kappa = 0.08; % kappa = PC proliferation (h^-1)
epsilon = 0.04; % epsilon = PC death (h^-1)
zeta = 0.24; % zeta = PC attachment (uM^-1 h^-1)
nu = 5E-3; % nu = PC detachment (h^-1)
eta = 0.01; % eta = Maturity increase (h^-1)
mu = 0.01; % mu = Maturity decrease (h^-1)
cep = 0.3; % cep = Threshold bound VEGF for EC proliferation
cd = 0.1; % cd = Threshold bound VEGF for EC death
ca = 0.3; % ca = Threshold bound Ang2 for EC proliferation
cpp = 0.02; % cpp = Threshold bound PDGF for PC proliferation
lambda = 8; % lambda = Ang2/Ang1 ratio for maturity decrease

%% Variable groupings

% Et = Total endothelial cells (uM)
Et = i(13) + i(14) + i(16);
% Pt = Total pericyte cells (uM)
Pt = i(15) + i(16);
% vb = Bound fraction of PDGFR-Beta receptors (None)
vb = i(3)/(i(2)+i(3));
% ab = Fraction of Tie2 receptors bound by Ang2 (None)
ab = i(9)/(i(7)+i(8)+i(9));
% pb = Bound fraction of PDGFR-Beta receptors (None)
pb = i(12)/(i(11)+i(12));

%% Model

dy = zeros(16,1);

% Biochemical Sub-Model

% Free VEGF
dy(1) = alphav/(((i(14)+i(16))/E0)+1) - v_kon*i(1)*i(2) + v_koff*i(3) - deltav*i(1);
% VEGFR2
dy(2) = - v_koff*i(1)*i(2) + (v_koff+v_kint)*i(3) + phi*theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/(ab^2+ca^2)))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(2);
% VEGF/VEGFR2
dy(3) = v_kon*i(1)*i(2) - (v_koff+v_kint)*i(3) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(3);
% Free Ang1
dy(4) = alphaa1*Pt - a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) + a1_koff*i(8) - deltaa1*i(4);
% Intracellular Ang2
dy(5) = alphaaw*(1+vb)*((A0/E0)*i(13)-i(5)) - deltaaw*i(5) - alphaa2*i(5)*((i(5))^2/((i(5))^2+((i(13)*A0)/(2*E0))^2)) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(5);
% Free Ang2
dy(6) = alphaa2*i(5)*((i(5))^2/((i(5))^2+((i(13)*A0)/(E0*2))^2)) - a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) + a2_koff*i(9) - deltaa2*i(6);
% Tie2
dy(7) = - a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) + (a1_koff+a1_kint)*i(8) - a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) + a2_koff*i(9) + phi*theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/(ab^2+ca^2)))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(7);
% Ang1/Tie2
dy(8) = a1_kon*i(4)*i(7) - (a1_koff+a1_kint)*i(8) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(8);
% Ang2/Tie2
dy(9) = a2_kon*i(6)*i(7) - a2_koff*i(9) - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*(i(13)/Et)*i(9);
% Free PDGF
dy(10) = alphap*i(13) - p_kon*i(10)*i(11) + p_koff*i(12) - deltap*i(10);
% PDGFR-Beta
dy(11) = - p_kon*i(10)*i(11) + p_koff*i(12) + phi*kappa*(pb^2/(pb^2+cpp^2))*(1-(Pt/P0))*i(15) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2))*i(11));
% PDGF/PDGFR-Beta
dy(12) = p_kon*i(10)*i(11) - p_koff*i(12) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(12);

% Cell Dynamics Sub-model

% Immature ECs
dy(13) = theta*(vb^2/(vb^2+cep^2))*(1+(ab^2/ab^2+ca^2))*(1-(Et/E0))*i(13) - rho*(cd^2/cd^2+vb^2)*i(13) - zeta*i(15)*i(13) + nu*i(16) + epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(16) - eta*(lambda^2/(lambda^2+(i(9)/i(8))^2))*i(13) + mu*((i(9)/i(8))^2/((i(9)/i(8))^2+lambda^2))*i(14);
% Mature ECs
dy(14) = - zeta*i(15)*i(14) + eta*(lambda^2/(lambda^2+(i(9)/i(8))^2))*i(13) + mu*((i(9)/i(8))^2/((i(9)/i(8))^2+lambda^2))*i(14);
% Free Pericytes
dy(15) = kappa*(pb^2/(pb^2+cpp^2))*(1-(Pt/P0))*i(15) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(15) - zeta*i(15)*(i(13)+i(14)) + nu*i(16);
% EC/PC Complex
dy(16) = zeta*i(15)*(i(13)+i(14)) - nu*i(16) - epsilon*((i(6)/A0)+(cpp^2/(cpp^2+pb^2)))*i(15);

end
```

The actual plot of the graph and final equations needed:

```
%% Dependent variables and variable groupings (Table 1)
% Definition and default initial conditions used for numerical simulations
% of dependent variables and variable groupings

% Angiogenic factors (VEGF) bind to VEGFR-2 receptors 
v = 8E-5; % v = Free VEGF concentration (uM)
rv = 6E-4; % rv = Total unbound VEGFR-2 receptors (uM)
bv = 6E-4; % bv = Total bound VEGFR-2 receptors (uM)

% Angiopoietin ligands (Ang1, Ang2) bind to Tie2 receptors
a1 = 8E-5; % a1 = Free Ang1 (uM)
aw = 8E-5; % aw = Total Ang2 stored in all WPBs (uM)
a2 = 8E-5; % a2 = Free Ang2 (uM)
ra = 6E-4; % ra = Total unbound Tie2 receptors (uM)
ba1 = 3E-4; % ba1 = Total bound Ang1/Tie2 (uM)
ba2 = 3E-4; % ba2 = Total bound Ang2/Tie2 (uM)

% PDGF-B binds to PDGFR-Beta receptors
p = 8E-5; % p = PDGF-B (uM)
rp = 4E-4; % rp = Total unbound PDGFR-Beta (uM)
bp = 4E-4; % rp = Total bound PDGFR-Beta (uM)

% Endothelial cells (EC) and pericyte cells (PC)
Ei = 4E-9; % Ei = Number density of immature ECs (uM)
Em = 8E-9; % Em = Number density of mature ECs (uM)
P = 8E-9; % P = Number density of free pericytes (uM)
Ep = 0; % Ep = Number density of ECs with pericyte coverage (uM)

%Initial condition vector
%    1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16    
i = [v rv bv a1 aw a2 ra ba1 ba2 p rp bp Ei Em P Ep];

%% Integration 

timespan = [0 200]; %200 days
[t1,y1] = ode45(@derivatives1,timespan,i);
[t2,y2] = ode45(@derivatives2,timespan,i);

%% Figure 3 plots 

figure('Name','Numerical simulations of the full model')

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(t1, y1(:,13),t1,y1(:,14),t1,y1(:,15),t1,y1(:,16))
xlabel('Time (days)')
ylabel('Normalised Density')

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(t2,y2(:,13),t2,y2(:,14),t2,y2(:,15),t2,y2(:,16))
xlabel('Time (days)')
ylabel('Normalised Density')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the solution you calculate before the ODE solver fails, it looks very different to the figure in the paper, which suggests that you are not solving the same equations. Indeed, if you look closely, there are a few typos e.g. in your definition of equation 13 you have (amongst other terms)

```
 - rho*(cd^2/cd^2+vb^2)*i(13)
```

which should be

```
 - rho*(cd^2/(cd^2+vb^2))*i(13)
```

(note the extra brackets). I would strongly recommend defining a function

```
function frac = H(a,b)
frac = a^2/(a^2 + b^2);
end
```

And using this in your equation definitions. So double check all your equations.

I imagine that the typos mean your system of ODEs is no longer well defined, and you've ended up dividing by 0 at some point or something similar.

Edit: have also noticed that you define your integration timespan in units of days, whilst all the parameters are defined in units of hours (or inverse hours).

Comment: Thank you :) it really helped